# Alternative to send_keys() - selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to write faster alternative of this Python code:

```
driver.get(myUrl)
message = driver.find_element_by_id('message')
send = driver.find_element_by_id('submit')

for _ in range(myRange):
    message.send_keys(myText)
    send.click()
```

As an alternative, tried to execute JavaScript with Selenium using `execute_script()` and `execute_async _script()`:

```
myJS = "document.getElementById('message').setAttribute('value', 'myText')"

for _ in range(myRange):
    driver.execute_script(myJs)
    send.click()
```

Both of them stopped after first loop cycle without any error.

What prevents the second script from looping through the whole range?
And are there any other fast alternatives to `send_keys()`?

Comment: You can populate the clipboard and then paste the text.  (send keys of ctrl-v)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the context of the test and why you are doing it,  but this is how it should be done.

```
driver.get(myUrl)

for _ in range(myRange):
    # I would suggest using the explicit wait for the element staleness check here before
    # entering the text
    driver.find_element_by_id('message').send_keys(myText)
    driver.find_element_by_id('submit').click()
```

Comment: This fails after the very first iteration for some reason.

Comment: Are you getting any message after the first iteration?